# How to cast an object into other interface

Tags: c#, .net, interface, casting

Here is my code

The `IDevice` interface is used to state that the class is a device of the `MessageBus`.

```cs
public interface IDevice
{
    int ID{ get;}
}
```

The `ISubscriber<>` use to state that the class is a subscriber and subscribed to `TMessage`.

```cs
public interface ISubscriber<TMessage> where TMessage : IMessage
{
    void Listen(TMessage message);
}
```

The `IMessage` use to state a message.

```cs
public interface IMessage { }
```

Here defined a message and a device subscribed to the message

```cs
public class TestMessage : IMessage { }

public class TestDevice : IDevice, ISubscriber<TestMessage>
```

And here come the problem, how can I convert the `TestDevice` from `IDevice` to `ISubscriberList`

```cs
public class MessageBus
{
    //key: Type of message
    public Dictionary<Type, List<ISubscriber<IMessage>>> SubscriberList { get; }

    //...

    public void Subscribe(IDevice device)
    {
        var deviceInfo = device.GetType();
        var isSubscriber = deviceInfo.GetInterfaces().Any(item => item.IsGenericType && 
        if (isSubscriber)
        {
            var subscriptionList = deviceInfo.GetInterfaces().Cast<Type>().ToList().FindAll(item => item.IsGenericType && item.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ISubscriber<>));
            foreach (var subscription in subscriptionList)
            {
                var message = subscription.GenericTypeArguments.First();
                if (!SubscriberList.ContainsKey(message))
                {
                    SubscriberList.Add(message, new List<ISubscriber<IMessage>>());
                }
                //Here is the problem come from, how to cast the device from IDevice into ISubscriber<TestMessage> or ISubScriber<message>
                SubscriberList[message].Add(device);

            }

        }
    }

    //...
}
```

Sorry if it's a dump question.

Comment: You can't cast an `IDevice` to the unrelated interface `ISubscriber<>`. The two interfaces have no inheritance relation. You can cast `TestDevice` to any of the interfaces though. If you want all devices to work as subscribers, you need to have `IDevice` inherit from `ISubscriber`

Comment: So is there a method to convert `IDevice` to its real class, like `TestDevice` in here?

Comment: The real question is why are you using `IDevice` when you really need `ISubscriber<IMessage>`? If you expect `IDevice` to be an `ISubscriber` why not have it inherit from `ISubscriber` ?

Comment: I expected to have other interface like `IClient`, the device can be an `IClient` but not an `ISubscriber`.

Comment: If you change ISubscriber to `public interface ISubscriber<out TMessage> where TMessage : IMessage
{
    void Listen(IMessage message);
}` you'll be able to assign or pass TestDevice to any variable or parameter expecting `ISubscriber<IMessage>`. If you try to cast one interface to an unrelated one, you're doing it wrong

Answer (score 0):

you can check the type and cast objects using `is`:

```
if(device is ISubscriber<TestMessage> subscriber){
     // Use subscriber
}
```

You should however be fairly careful in using these kinds of patterns since it can easily result in a method behaving differently depending on the type of object it is given. That might be fine if the only change is better performance, but that does not seem to be the case here.

In this case it might be better to take two separate parameters, one for the device and one for the subscriber. This might be the same object, but the method should not care about that. You could also create a `IDeviceSubscriber` interface that inherits from both.

you should also be careful using generics `ISubscriber<TestMessage>` is a completely different type from `ISubscriber<TMessage>`. One might be convertable to the other if they are [variant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/), but there are a bunch of rules for using co/contra variance.

Without knowing the problem domain it is difficult to provide more specific recommendations.